# How can I use the function's return right away?

Tags: python

I'm doing python developing.

```
class Figure():

    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.dots = a
        self.height = b
        self.width = c

    def calcArea(self):
        area = self.height * self.width
        print(area)

    def Tellarea(self):
        x= calcArea(self)
        print(self.figure+" area :", x)
```

In this case, the x part is said to be wrong.
What should I do to write the function values directly from another function?

I'm a beginner coder. Sorry for the cute question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the value using the `return` statement as:

```
def calcArea(self):
    area = self.height * self.width
    print(area)
    return area
```

By default, a `None` value is returned if nothing is returned explicitly.

Also, you need to call class methods with `self` and not pass `self` as argument:

```
x = self.calcArea()
```